# NavigationBar Translucent Animation

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a ViewController which starts with a translucent navigationbar with clear background

```
navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
navigationBar.barTintColor = .clear
```

I have `scrollView` as the first child and scrollView's `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` is set to `.never`. Now when I scroll the view and `scrollView.contentOffset.y > 200` I decided to change the navigationbar as

```
navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationBar.barTintColor = .someColor
```

the scroll view get pushed down. I understand that when the view is supposed to be below the navigation bar when it is not translucent. But this makes my scroll effect look ugly. I did little research and found that I can enable `Under the top bar` option from storyboard, nut unfortunately I am building my using swift, and not using storyboard. I also tried using `edgesForExtendedLayout = [.top]` but did not work form me.

I wanted was a smooth scrolling behaviour while scrolling, with Navigationbar changing the property of translucent with respect to scrolling contentOffset.

Comment: Can you post full project code somewhere to check what you have (remove any unrelated code)? May be you may add extra view at the top and make it visible instead of changing navigation bar?

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov nop I have not added any extra view. You can create a sample ViewController with either scrollView or Table view and make the navigation bar transparent when the view is loaded, and after scrolling the view look for y offset and change the value of navigation bar to transparent/ (translucent) back to false. you will see the problem on the scroll animation.

Comment: there is no such issue - https://youtu.be/cJpEZFNZdyU . Provide you source code to let people help you.

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov you have made UINavigationbar black color, My question is make it gone, like it hides when you scroll so that the UILabel starts below the status bar not below Navigation bar.